# Configure log4j.properties to output error to files

Tags: logging, log4j

I have multiple java classes and want to write debug and error output to different log files as well as different locations. How can I achieve that with log4j.properties?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the messages. However, the filters are only available via an XML configuration file, `log4j.xml`.

- #### [`org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelRangeFilter.html)

  If you want to specify the lower range and the upper range for an appender:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN"
                                       "log4j.dtd">
  <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

      <!-- DEBUG appender -->
      <appender name="DEBUGFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
          <param name="file" value="debug.log" />
          <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout" />
          <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
              <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
              <param name="LevelMax" value="DEBUG" />
          </filter>
      </appender>

      <!-- ERROR appender -->
      <appender name="ERRORFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
          <param name="file" value="error.log" />
          <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout" />
          <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
              <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
              <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR" />
          </filter>
      </appender>

      <!-- root -->
      <root>
          <priority value="ALL" />
          <appender-ref ref="DEBUGFILE" />
          <appender-ref ref="ERRORFILE" />
      </root>

  </log4j:configuration>
  ```
- #### [`org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelMatchFilter.html)

  If you want to filter a single level:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN"
                                       "log4j.dtd">
  <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

      <!-- DEBUG appender -->
      <appender name="DEBUGFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
          <param name="file" value="debug.log" />
          <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout" />
          <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
              <param name="levelToMatch" value="DEBUG" />
          </filter>
      </appender>

      <!-- ERROR appender -->
      <appender name="ERRORFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
          <param name="file" value="error.log" />
          <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout" />
          <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
              <param name="levelToMatch" value="ERROR" />
          </filter>
      </appender>

      <!-- root -->
      <root>
          <priority value="ALL" />
          <appender-ref ref="DEBUGFILE" />
          <appender-ref ref="ERRORFILE" />
      </root>

  </log4j:configuration>
  ```